# Create TensorFlow model from dataframe wihtout keras

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow and I was wondering how to make a simple model with `tensorflow v1.12` ONLY not using `ts.keras` for the following dataframe:

```
   from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
import pandas as pd
X, y = make_moons(n_samples=500, noise=0.1)
xdf=pd.DataFrame(X,columns=['f1','f2'])
ydf=pd.DataFrame(y,columns=['label'])
display(xdf.head(5))
display(ydf.head(5))
```

[image]

I already created a model with `ts.keras` but I'm just curious how to do it with Tensorflow only

Answer (score 0):

It is the exact sample from:

[Tensorflow](https://tf-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/wide/)
or
[linearclassifier](https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow~python/tf/contrib/learn/linearclassifier/)

> The model also automatically learns a bias term, which controls the
>   prediction one would make without observing any features (see the
>   section “How Logistic Regression Works” for more explanations). The
>   learned model files will be stored in model_dir.

```
import tempfile
import urllib
train_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
test_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
urllib.urlretrieve("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data", train_file.name)
urllib.urlretrieve("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.test", test_file.name)

model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
m = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=[
  gender, native_country, education, occupation, workclass, marital_status, race,
  age_buckets, education_x_occupation, age_buckets_x_education_x_occupation],
  model_dir=model_dir)
```